# Regex pattern to capture all folders in URL including forward slash

Tags: django, regex, url, django-urls, regex-group

I want to **match dynamically created URLs** which can have **multiple folders**. Need some regex pattern for this. For ex.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/:user_id/:foldersa/:folders1/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/:user_id/:foldersb/:folders2/:folders3/:folders4
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/:user_id/:foldersc/:folders2/
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/:user_id/:foldersd/:folders1/:folders2/
```

so till `BASE_URL/api/:user_id/` is common. I can catch user_id but want to catch other params after user_id on a single string variable.
after that, there can be any number of folders and I want to catch them all in one single string variable.
like for first URL string variable caught will be `"foldera/folder1/"` and for next url string variable will be `"folderb/folder2/folder3/folder4"` along with fwd slashes.

What regex pattern should I write in urls.py for capturing this folders?
I tried with
`re_path(r'(?P<user_id>[-\w]+)/(?P<customUrl>(.*?)(?:\/)?$)/.*', customLink, name='customLink'),`

but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: If I see four "endpoints" in one row they surely cannot be endpoints at all. Why do people call folders in a URL path this way? Or "variables"? By common sense either the whole address is ONE endpoint or the last folder is.

Comment: Ohk. Thanks for simplifying it. I wanted a quick solution and was out of word (folder) so named it endpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match all but the last optional trailing slash:

```
re_path(r'(?P<user_id>[-\w]+)/(?P<custom_url>.*?)/?$', customLink, name='customLink'),
```

in the view you can then split the endpoints with:

```
def customLink(request, user_id, custom_url):
    endpoints = custom_url.split('/')
    # …
```

You can also make use of a path converter:

```
# app_name/converters.py

class EndpointsConverter:
    regex = ".*?"
    
    def to_python(self, value):
        return value.split('/')
    
    def to_url(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, str):
            return value
        return '/'.join(value)
```

then you can work with a path converter:

```
from django.urls import path, register_converter
from app_name.converters import EndpointsConverter

register_converter(EndpointsConverter, 'endpoints')

urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:user_id>/<endpoints:endpoints>/', customLink, name='customLink'),
    # …
]
```

this will automatically split (and join) the endpoints by the slashes.